# Iteration is quit after first iteration

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to compare two different List and remove the duplicates. However, the two lists have two different object types and only common attribute is app name.

Here is the code,

```
public List<TvAppsType> getAvailableAppsTypesByCompanyIdSecond(int comapnyId) {
    // put apps to the model that belong to the given company id
    TVAppService tvAppService = new TVAppService();
    List<ThreatviewApp> apps = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<ThreatviewApp>();
    apps = tvAppService.getAllAppsforCompanyId(comapnyId);

    // get list of app types
    TvAppTypeService types = new TvAppTypeService();
    List<TvAppsType> apptypes = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<TvAppsType>();
    apptypes = types.getAppTypes();
    // add the items to collection for removing
    for(TvAppsType app : apptypes){
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("app : " + app.getAppType_name());
    }

    Iterator<TvAppsType> itertypes = apptypes.iterator();
    Iterator<ThreatviewApp> it = apps.iterator();
    while (itertypes.hasNext()) {
        TvAppsType apptype = itertypes.next();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ThreatviewApp tvapp = it.next();
            if (tvapp.getApp_name().trim().equals(apptype.getAppType_name().trim())) {
                itertypes.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    for(TvAppsType app : apptypes){
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("app : " + app.getAppType_name());
    }

    return apptypes;
}
```

Problem is this works only in first iteration, I suspect that after the List is modified, the iteration behavior is unspecified.

> void remove() Removes from the underlying collection the last element
>   returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be
>   called only once per call to next(). The behavior of an iterator is
>   unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the
>   iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

As I am trying to modify the lists runtime, I used `CopyOnWriteArrayList`
bascically, I followed this article [article](http://www.journaldev.com/378/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-an-iterator)

why the iteration stop after first one? How to fix this and remove all duplicates?

Comment: It might be more efficient to map both lists into a `HashMap<String,Object>`. After that, the map's values list will not contain duplicates (and can be separated by checking classes). The order of insertion into the Map determines which list is preferred to remain. (This is O(m+n) against O(m*n).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset the iterator of the inner loop if you wish to iterate more than once on the `apps` list. Otherwise, the inner while loop will iterate over the `apps` list only one time, after which `it.hasNext()` will be false.

```
Iterator<TvAppsType> itertypes = apptypes.iterator();
while (itertypes.hasNext()) {
    TvAppsType apptype = itertypes.next();
    Iterator<ThreatviewApp> it = apps.iterator(); // the inner iterator must be
                                                  // initialized in each iteration
                                                  // of the outer loop
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ...
```

Comment: thanks your answere works, but we modify `Iterator<TvAppsType> itertypes = apptypes.iterator();` . so don't we need to reset this iterator?

Comment: @mankadanka You only iterate once over `apptypes`, so you don't have to reset that iterator. You just have to make sure you are not attempting to remove the same element more than once (as cybersam mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Eran's answer, you have another problem. Once you have removed a `TvAppsType` (in the inner while loop), you should never attempt to remove the same object again. Also, quitting the inner loop as soon as possible will speed up your algorithm.

So, the inner loop should look like this:

```
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ThreatviewApp tvapp = it.next();
        if (tvapp.getApp_name().trim().equals(apptype.getAppType_name().trim())) {
            itertypes.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution -- it is a refinement of @Erin's answer.